# Proof Verification: $\Omega_{X \times Y/S} \cong p_1^* \Omega_{X/S} \oplus p_2^* \Omega_{Y/S} $

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, solution-verification

This is exercise II.8.2 in Hartshorne's 'Algebraic Geometry'. Essentially, we have $X$, $Y$ two $S$-schemes and I would like to show $\Omega_{X \times_S Y/S} \cong p_1^* \Omega_{X/S} \oplus p_2^* \Omega_{Y/S}$ where $p_1, p_2$ are the canonical projections. We start by making two observations. The maps $X \times_S Y \stackrel{p_1}\to X \to S$ induce the cotangent sequence of $\mathcal{O}_{X \times Y}$ modules $$p_1^* \Omega_{X/S} \to \Omega_{X \times Y/S} \to \Omega_{X \times Y/X} \to 0$$ and there is a canonical isomorphism $\Omega_{X \times Y/X} \cong p_2^* \Omega_{Y/S}$ so that our exact sequence is $$p_1^* \Omega_{X/S} \to \Omega_{X \times Y/S} \to p_2^* \Omega_{Y/S} \to 0.$$ By symmetry, we know that there is also an exact sequence $$p_2^* \Omega_{Y/S} \to \Omega_{X \times Y/S} \to p_1^* \Omega_{X/S} \to 0$$ and I claim that the maps above are sections of the maps in the first exact sequence, so that it is a split exact sequence, proving the result.

To prove that these maps are sections, it suffices to check affine locally (right?), where these sequences restrict to the cotangent sequence of rings. As such, we take $X = \operatorname{Spec} A$, $Y = \operatorname{Spec} B$ and $S = \operatorname{Spec} C$ so that the cotangent sequence (induced by $C \to A \to A \otimes_CB$) becomes $$(A \otimes_CB) \otimes_A \Omega_{A/C} \to \Omega_{A \otimes B/C} \to \Omega_{A \otimes B/A} \to 0$$ where the first map is $c \otimes db \mapsto cdb$ and the second map is $dc \mapsto dc$. Now as before, we have an isomorphism $\Omega_{A \otimes B/B} \cong (A \otimes_C B) \otimes_B \Omega_{B/C}$ is the restriction of $\Omega_{X \times Y/X} \cong p_2^* \Omega_{Y/S}$. Now the isomorphism $\Omega_{A \otimes B/B} \to (A \otimes_C B) \otimes_B \Omega_{B/C}$ sending $d(a \otimes c) \mapsto (a \otimes 1) \otimes dc $. Putting this all together we have an exact sequence

$$(A \otimes_C B) \otimes_A \Omega_{A/C} \to \Omega_{A \otimes B/C} \stackrel{\pi}\to (A \otimes_C B) \otimes_B \Omega_{B/C} \to 0$$

where the first map is $c \otimes db \mapsto cd(b \otimes 1)$ and the second map is  $d(a \otimes c) \mapsto (a \otimes 1) \otimes dc $. Symmetrically we then have the restriction of the other exact sequence

$$(A \otimes_C B) \otimes_B \Omega_{B/C} \stackrel{\iota}\to \Omega_{A \otimes B/C} \to (A \otimes_C B) \otimes_A \Omega_{A/C} \to 0.$$ We note that $\iota$ is given explicitly by $(a \otimes b) \otimes db' \mapsto (a \otimes b) d(1 \otimes b)$. Now we evaluate $$\pi(\iota(a \otimes b \otimes dc)) = \pi(a \otimes b d(1 \otimes c)) = a \otimes b \pi(d(1 \otimes c)) = (a \otimes b)(1 \otimes 1) \otimes dc = a \otimes b \otimes dc$$ so that $\pi \circ \iota = \text{Id}$. Hence, $\iota$ is a injective and the sequences split, proving the result.

Is this correct, and is this roughly the right way to do this problem? Working with the explicit maps is tedious but it seems to give the right answer as long as I didn't make any mistakes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.

You might be able to gain some slight improvements by simplifying your tensor products a bit (i.e. $(A\otimes_C B)\otimes_B\Omega_{B/C} \cong A\otimes_C \Omega_{B/C}$) but this is pretty much the right argument. This is a pattern in algebraic geometry: frequently one has something to prove and by a series of reductions it suffices to verify it in the affine case, where it turns in to a problem of pushing explicit elements of rings around.

Comment: I know we’re not supposed to do this here but thanks for your continued help KReiser. I really really appreciate it.

Comment: I'll also add that the reason I chose the notation I did was to emphasize that this is the pullback of $\Omega_{B/C}$ to $\operatorname{Spec} A \otimes_C B$ but it is messy and probably unnecessary.